# Is it possible to install office and make it accesible to all users in a workstation?

Tags: microsoft-office, disk-image

I fully expect the users to activate the office product by themselves.

But I want to build an Windows machine image that will have the Office product properly registered their COM class ID registered. We need for some office automation task.

[image]

But now for a normal user, although he/she can launch the office product, we cannot run our script which invokes office products like this

```
   import win32com.client
   pc = win32com.client.Dispatch(winserver2012_comcls)
```

But apparently the COM CLS is not in registered so my script failed.

It seems like I have to run installation in the user account.

Is there any way I can do when I install office products as an Administrator?

Comment: Isn't Office typically licensed per machine instead of per user?

Comment: That's why I did not expect the WIN32COM call to fail... I didn't happen to me in the past, so not sure if I missed something

Comment: To be asked for permissions to run Office as a normal user, you must have installed Office as an Administrator, but failed to install it so everyone can use it.  There should have been an option within the installer that offers that option.

Comment: I probably have to reinstall... BTW I am still using an old version office 2013

Comment: Are you using shared computer activation [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-shared-computer-activation-for-office-365-proplus) ?

Comment: No. Actually because of the strict internet settings, I can't even open the MS login page